# Linear algebra T- invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $ T $ be the linear operator on $ \Bbb R^3 $ which is represented by the matrix $ A = $
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$.
Let $ W $ be the null space of $ T - 2I $. Prove that $ W $ has no complementary $ T $-invariant subspaces.

Answer (score 1):

Since the null space $N_1$ of $T-2I$ (which is spanned by the second standard basis vector) is of dimension$~1$, any complement of it is of dimension $3-1=2$. Therefore any complement $C$ of $N_1$ intersects the null space $N_2$ of $(T-2I)^2$ (which is spanned by the first two standard basis vectors) in a subspace of dimension$~1$ (the only $2$-dimensional subspace that does not do so is $N_2$ itself, but it is not complementary to $N_1$). Now $N_2$ is $T$-stable, and if $C$ is also $T$-stable, then $C\cap N_2$ is also $T$-stable. But $N_2$ contains only one $T$-stable subspace if dimension$~1$ (consisting of eigenvectors for$~T$) namely $N_1$, but that space cannot be contained in its own complement$~C$.

Answer (score 0):

First observe that $\operatorname{ker}(T-2I)=\langle e_2\rangle$

Let $\mathbb{R}^3=W\oplus V$ for some $T$-invariant subspace $V$. As $V$ is $T$-invariant, it is also $(T-2I)$ invariant. Thus if $v=\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2+\lambda_3e_3$, then $\lambda_3e_3=(T-2I)^2v\in V$. Now it is not possible that $\lambda_3=0$ for all $v\in V$, since otherwise we wouldn't have $\mathbb{R}^3=W+V$. Thus also $e_3\in V$.

Now since $W$ is a subspace we also have that $\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2\in V$, but then also $(T-2I)(\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2)\in V$. The rest of the proof is similar, I leave it to the reader.